# Using jquery append function, but not working for <ngx dropzone>

Tags: jquery, angular

I am using jquery .append function, but this is not working for , is there any solution for that

```html
    <ngx-dropzone [showPreviews]="true" #dropzone [showPreviews]="true" [preserveFiles]="false" [accept]="'image/png,image/jpeg'" [label]="'This is a custom label text'"></ngx-dropzone>

    <div id="appendData">
    </div>

    <div (click)="dataload()">Append</div>

    dataload(){
    $('appendData').append(
    `<ngx-dropzone [showPreviews]="true" #dropzone [showPreviews]="true" [preserveFiles]="false" [maxFileSize]="2000" [accept]="'image/png,image/jpeg'" [label]="'This is a custom label text'"></ngx-dropzone>`
    );
    }
```

Comment: sorry, i am using this first time, hope so you understand my wording, i am using .append function but it is not supporting <ngx dropzone> tag, is there any solution for that

Comment: Your selector must be replaced with $('#appendData')

Comment: But still not working.  Working will all other tags except <ngx dropzone>

Comment: Is there any angular append function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ngFor` to dynamically create `ngx-dropdone`

### https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-1nbyha?file=src/app/app.component.ts

**app.component.ts**

```
export class AppComponent {

  list = [] as any[];

  constructor() { }

  public dataload() {
    this.list.push({
      property1: 123
    });
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<ngx-dropzone [showPreviews]="true" #dropzone [showPreviews]="true" [preserveFiles]="false" [accept]="'image/png,image/jpeg'" [label]="'This is a custom label text'"></ngx-dropzone>

<div *ngFor="let data of list" >
  <ngx-dropzone [showPreviews]="true" #dropzone [showPreviews]="true" [preserveFiles]="false" [maxFileSize]="2000" [accept]="'image/png,image/jpeg'" [label]="'This is a custom label text'"></ngx-dropzone>

</div>

<div (click)="dataload()">Append</div>
```